# Accessing Multidimensional Array Values without recursive functions and/or loops

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have index ponter, for example `5-1-key2-3`.

And my `array` has its `address`:

```
array(
  '5'=>array(
     '1'=>array(
        'key2'=>array(
             '3'=>'here it is - 5-1-key2-3 key address'
         )
      )
   )
)
```

which equals to

```
$arr[5][1][key2][3]='here it is - 5-1-key2-3 key address';
```

I know I can build the recursive function to access this value.

But I'm curious is it possible to achieve this without recursion and building user's functions **and/or loops**.

Probably it can be done with `variable variables` feature in `php`.

Comment: Post your array values with expected output

Comment: you need multidimensional array dynamic accessor, check my answer

Comment: check my second answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$keys = explode('-', '5-1-key2-3');

// start from the root of the array and progress through the elements
$temp = $arr;
foreach ($keys as $key_value)
{
    $temp = $temp[$key_value];
}

// this will give you $arr["5"]["1"]["key2"]["3"] element value
echo $temp;
```

Comment: after I see your answer, I understand that I didnt understand the question in the first place :(

Comment: @Bob0t would you tell how you understood my question at first? =)

Comment: @talsibony would you tell how you understood my question at first? =)

Comment: I thought that you are asking if you can access it in some kind of looping but without a recursion which was like a change question :)

Comment: `$a[a][b][c]='123'; $b='a["a"]["b"]["c"]'; echo ${$b}; //outputs nothing`

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev  I think there should be `=&$temp["$key_value"];` instead of `=$temp["$key_value"]` to be workable

Comment: It worked as it is when I tested it. Make sure the array keys are defined as this $arr['5'] ... not as this $arr[5]. That may confuse the PHP interpreter :)

Comment: but it involves `foreach` loop. I didn't mentioned it in my question at first, and I'll accept your answer if no other solution would be given here

Comment: I think I can probably provide another solution later. I will update my answer if I find one that is better.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev You may try, but `variable variables` approach seems impossible. At least I tried everything with it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @elDude just undeleted my answer, this uses some kind of recursion cuz its going far into the array by re-attributing the $tmp var with the next level value. That's why i though this was not appropriate after a re-reading of your question ^^

Comment: @YasenZhelev Btw if you want to do this you need to use eval, which i deprecate so much for security evident reasons ... `eval( "return \$array{$keys};" )`

Comment: @elDude this should be the accepted answer, its very elegant and answer your question. but  I would recommend to add isset() condition to $temp["$key_value"];  in order to avoid accessing to undefined index, also the double quetes here are not needed "$key_value" you can just use the $temp[$key_value]

Comment: `$temp = $temp["$key_value"]` is equivalent to `$temp = $temp[$key_value]`, in fact PHP doesn't care about it's a string a int key, for him it's alltime a string ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**

Here is a way I deprecate so much, because of security, but if you are sure of what you are doing :

```
$key = 'a-b-c-d';
$array = <<your array>>;
$keys = explode('-', $key);
// we can surely do something better like checking for each one if its a string or int then adding or not the `'`
$final_key = "['".implode("']['", $keys)."']";
$result = eval("return \$array{$final_key};");
```

---

There is a class I wrote inspired from something I read on the web don't really remember where but anyway, this can helps you :

```
/**
 * Class MultidimensionalHelper
 *
 * Some help about multidimensional arrays
 * like dynamic array_key_exists, set, and get functions
 *
 * @package Core\Utils\Arrays
 */
class MultidimensionalHelper
{
    protected $keySeparator = '.';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function keySeparator()
    {
        return $this->keySeparator;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $keySeparator
     */
    public function setKeySeparator($keySeparator)
    {
        $this->keySeparator = $keySeparator;
    }



    /**
     * Multidimensional array dynamic array_key_exists
     *
     * @param $key      String Needle
     * @param $array    Array  Haystack
     * @return bool     True if found, false either
     */
    public function exists($key, $array)
    {
        $keys = explode($this->keySeparator(), $key);

        $tmp = $array;

        foreach($keys as $k)
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($k, $tmp))
            {
                return false;
            }

            $tmp = $tmp[$k];
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Multidimensional array dynamic getter
     *
     *
     * @param $key      String  Needle
     * @param $array    Array   Haystack
     * @return mixed    Null if key not exists or the content of the key
     */
    public function get($key, $array)
    {
        $keys = explode($this->keySeparator(), $key);
        $lkey = array_pop($keys);

        $tmp = $array;

        foreach($keys as $k)
        {
            if(!isset($tmp[$k]))
            {
                return null;
            }

            $tmp = $tmp[$k];
        }

        return $tmp[$lkey];
    }

    /**
     * Multidimensional array dynamic setter
     *
     * @param String    $key
     * @param Mixed     $value
     * @param Array     $array  Array to modify
     * @param Bool      $return
     * @return Array    If $return is set to TRUE (bool), this function
     *                  returns the modified array instead of directly modifying it.
     */
    public function set($key, $value, &$array)
    {
        $keys = explode($this->keySeparator(), $key);
        $lkey = array_pop($keys);

        $tmp = &$array;

        foreach($keys as $k)
        {
            if(!isset($tmp[$k]) || !is_array($tmp[$k]))
            {
                $tmp[$k] = array();
            }

            $tmp = &$tmp[$k];
        }

        $tmp[$lkey] = $value;

        unset($tmp);
    }
}
```

Then use :

```
$MDH = new MultidimensionalHelper();

$MDH->setKeySeparator('-');

$arr = [ 
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => 'good value',
        ],
        'c' => 'wrong value',
    ],
    'b' => [
        'c' => 'wrong value',
    ]
];

$key = 'a-b-c';
$val = $MDH->get($key, $arr);

var_dump($val);
```

Here is the content of the get function if you don't find it in Class code :

```
public function get($key, $array)
{
    $keys = explode($this->keySeparator(), $key);
    $lkey = array_pop($keys);

    $tmp = $array;

    foreach($keys as $k)
    {
        if(!isset($tmp[$k]))
        {
            return null;
        }

        $tmp = $tmp[$k];
    }

    return $tmp[$lkey];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modifications after I got better understanding of the question I think you can do it with eval:

```
<?php

function getArrValuesFromString($string, $arr) {
  $stringArr = '$arr[\'' . str_replace('-', "']['", $string) . '\']';

  eval("\$t = " . $stringArr . ";");
  return $t;
}

$arr[5][1]['key2'][3] = '1here it is - 5-1-key2-3 key address';
$string = '5-1-key2-3';
echo getArrValuesFromString($string, $arr); //1here it is - 5-1-key2-3 key address
```

Comment: quite horibble approach =)\

Comment: LOL yes eval can be evil.. but this solution will work, and since Yasen Zhelev took the nice approach I left with the ugly one...

Comment: array keys come from outside (`post` or `get`). Could be dangerous